# JDBC connection fails to connect Teradata from apache spark

Tags: java, jdbc, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have tried many different approaches to connect to our Teradata environment from Apache Spark using JDBC connection. Below is the code I have been using.

I made sure that my JDBC drivers are correct since I am using same drivers to connect to Teradata from other platforms.

I am also adding driver Jars when running the spark-shell 
`./bin/spark-shell --jars /home/path/*.jar --driver-class-path /home/path/*.jar`

Any help would be appreciated!

```
val jdbcDF = sqlContext.load("jdbc", Map(
  "url" -> "jdbc:teradata://<server_name>, TMODE=TERA, user=my_user, password=*****",
  "dbtable" -> "schema.table_name",
  "driver" -> "com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver"))
```

Stack trace for exceptions:

```
warning: there were 1 deprecation warning(s); re-run with -deprecation for details
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.AbstractFileClassLoader.findClass(AbstractFileClassLoader.scala:83)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.jdbc.package$DriverRegistry$.register(jdbc.scala:227)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.jdbc.DefaultSource.createRelation(JDBCRelation.scala:94)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.sources.ResolvedDataSource$.apply(ddl.scala:265)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:114)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext.load(SQLContext.scala:1242)
        at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:19)
        at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:27)
        at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:29)
        at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:31)
        at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:33)
        at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:35)
        at $iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:37)
        at $iwC.<init>(<console>:39)
        at <init>(<console>:41)
        at .<init>(<console>:45)
        at .<clinit>(<console>)
        at .<init>(<console>:7)
        at .<clinit>(<console>)
        at $print(<console>)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(SparkIMain.scala:1065)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$Request.loadAndRun(SparkIMain.scala:1338)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.loadAndRunReq$1(SparkIMain.scala:840)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:871)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:819)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.reallyInterpret$1(SparkILoop.scala:857)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.interpretStartingWith(SparkILoop.scala:902)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.reallyInterpret$1(SparkILoop.scala:875)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.interpretStartingWith(SparkILoop.scala:902)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.reallyInterpret$1(SparkILoop.scala:875)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.interpretStartingWith(SparkILoop.scala:902)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.reallyInterpret$1(SparkILoop.scala:875)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.interpretStartingWith(SparkILoop.scala:902)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.command(SparkILoop.scala:814)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.processLine$1(SparkILoop.scala:657)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.innerLoop$1(SparkILoop.scala:665)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$loop(SparkILoop.scala:670)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply$mcZ$sp(SparkILoop.scala:997)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:945)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:945)
        at scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader$.savingContextLoader(ScalaClassLoader.scala:135)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process(SparkILoop.scala:945)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.process(SparkILoop.scala:1059)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.main(Main.scala:31)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.Main.main(Main.scala)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:664)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:169)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:192)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:111)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

Comment: As the class could not be found, the driver's jar is not in the classpath. Did you include it? And, is the package and class name of the driver correct? `com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver`

Comment: Yes, I am inlcuding correct jars when firing up spark shell  ```./bin/spark-shell --jars /home/path/*.jar --driver-class-path /home/path/*.jar```.

Also I am using same class name to connect to JDBC Teradata from R.

Comment: I don't know Spark enough but the jar is surely not in the classpath. The `AbstractFileClassLoader` could not find it. Is the error message generated by the shell or by a server process in the cluster and then shown on the shell? Then the jar must also be copied to the classpath of the server process. The fact that  R has access to it could be that, it is somehow installed with the R module but not accessible from scala/java.

Comment: @PeterPaulKiefer - I certainly understand the point and trying to figure that out. But couldn't find a way to check weather the jars are included during runtime. Technically they should since I am running the shell with *path* pointing to these JDBC Jar files.

Answer (score 2):

I finally got this working. The reason it doesn't work with `--jars` is explained on the [spark docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.3.1/sql-programming-guide.html#jdbc-to-other-databases):

> The JDBC driver class must be visible to the primordial class loader
>   on the client session and on all executors. This is because Java’s
>   DriverManager class does a security check that results in it ignoring
>   all drivers not visible to the primordial class loader when one goes
>   to open a connection.

The solution is:

1. Copy the JDBC jars to each of your spark nodes in the cluster
2. Modify your `spark-defaults.conf` to add the extraClassPath option for your driver and executor

Add these to spark-defaults.conf:

- **spark.driver.extraClassPath**

  - /usr/lib/tdch/1.4/lib/terajdbc4.jar:/usr/lib/tdch/1.4/lib/tdgssconfig.jar
- **spark.executor.extraClassPath**

  - /usr/lib/tdch/1.4/lib/terajdbc4.jar:/usr/lib/tdch/1.4/lib/tdgssconfig.jar

If you are using Ambari, you can add these two properties under "Custom spark-defaults" and then restart Spark.

Comment: When you use --jars or SparkContext.addJar method to add a jar to the executor classpath.. does the Jar not add to the primordial classloader's classpath? 
I know this approach does not work for Drivers, but it should work for executors.. right?

Answer (score 0):

That error is because the jar containing the driver is not found at runtime. Even if you have that jar when you run your program, you also need to distribute it to all the nodes in the cluster. You can do that with:

```
sc.addJar("yourDriver.jar")
```

If you are using `spark-submit`, you can also add the additional jars with `--jars`:

```
./bin/spark-submit \
  --class <main-class>
  --master <master-url> \
  --jars jar1.jar
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have included both jdbc jar files ```./bin/spark-shell --jars /home/path/*.jar --driver-class-path /home/path/*.jar```. Also tried using ```sc.addJar("jar")``` but still getting same exception.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the connection to Teradata using Apache Spark is possible.
The above issue is because the spark-shell is not able to call the jars required for connecting to Teradata using Spark.
The 2 jars required for connecting to Teradata are terajdbc4.jar and tdgssconfig.jar.
Start your spark-shell by calling the jars explicitly using the below mention command.

```
spark-shell --jars /path/terajdbc4.jar,/path/tdgssconfig.jar

import spark.implicits._;

import spark.sql;

val sqlcontext=new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc);

val jdbcDF = sqlcontext.load("jdbc", Map("url" -> "jdbc:teradata://host/DBS_PORT=1025, TMODE=TERA, user=username, password=password","dbtable" -> "databasename.tablename","driver" -> "com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver"));

jdbcDF.coalesce(1).write.option("header", "true").csv("/path"); //To save the result as a csv file

exit();
```